# Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net

im trying to read the value from the excel using code but i have this exception [Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject(String PathName, String Class) +101
RRB_PO.Views_Coder.OpenExcel(String temp) +188

I already add the permission for the  Microsoft Excel Application but it doesnt solve the issue.
My code is as below:

```
     Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wbsXL As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet

    appXL = CreateObject("excel.application")
    appXL.Visible = True

    wbsXL = appXL.Workbooks
    wbXL = wbsXL.Open(fullPath)
    shXL = wbXL.ActiveSheet

    Dim xRng As Excel.Range = CType(shXL.Cells(8, 6), Excel.Range)
    Dim val2 As Object = xRng.Value()
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: *"I already add the permission for the Microsoft Excel Application"*. I'm not sure exactly what that means. Is Excel definitely installed?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeah it is already installed

Comment: The error message "...Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject..." does not match the code; the code is using `CreateObject`.  GetObject tries to retrieve an already running instance where-as CreateObject creates a new instance.

Comment: You tagged this `asp.net`, you do realize that automating Excel on a server is not supported, right?

Comment: @TnTinMn i mistakenly click the asp at the suggestions pop up. btw for the code name,  the getobject is the one when i tried to change how to call it. it is my first time using this.